# Where in an Eclipse plugin to I place an algorithm that utilises several views

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've got an Eclipse plugin that contains 4 views.  A piece of programming functionality must sit 'above' these views, tying them together. I'll call it the 'master'

Can anybody advise on the best location for this functionality?  Really, I want the 'master' to start once the application is open and the views have been initialised.

In my generated RCP application plugin I have an Activitor, a Client, a Perspective, an ApplicationActionBarAdvisor, and ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor, and an ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.  None of these seem suitable for hosting the 'master'.

**Edit**: after a little further investigation I suspect the ApplicationWindowAdvisor holds my answer.  It has a number of methods that may be overridden to *jump into* application lifecycle stages.  The ones that appear to relate to this problem appear to be:  **postStartup**, **postWindowOpen**, **postWindowCreate**

I'd appreciate any pointers on which method is called after all the views have been created/initialised.

**Edit 2**: more googling has exposed use of the **org.eclipse.ui.startup** 
extension point,  as **IStartup.earlyStartup()** is also run after the Workbench 
was completely started.

cheers,
Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could define an OSGi service (see the tutorial by Lars Vogel for detailed howto: http://www.vogella.de/articles/OSGi/article.html).

This service could be initialized either declaratively, or by using your plug-in activator; then each view could connect to this service.

On the other hand, if you want to communicate between the views, you could simple use the workbench selection service - in this case, all views are operating somewhat independent of each other, without central control.

**Edit** Responding to the changes in the question: neither proposed methods have anything to do with the opening (or closing) of the views. The **postStartup** is executed after the application starts; **postWindowOpen** is executed after the window is opened; while **postWindowCreate** is opened after the window is created, but before its opened.

The earlyStartup() makes it possible to execute after the workbench was started, but it still does not makes sure whether the corresponding views are opened - views have a different life-cycle then windows.

Globally, you have to provide some common service that can be used by each of the views; this can registered at most points of the application lifecycle - you should choose the one that fits your need best.

Comment: Could suggestion.  I like the work of Lars, I hadn't realised OSGI was a technology I should be considering for this (I was hoping to just extend what had been provided by the new plugin wizard - I've updated the question in the light of further research into this).

Comment: OSGi is already available in all RCP applications, so you could use it if you want to. However, I updated my answer to provide some feedback to your edited question.

Comment: "OSGI is already...". Yes, Zoltan, I appreciate it's in the RCP toolbox, it's just not in mine (yet) - so far it's one skill I've managed to avoid learning.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mixing concepts. Algorithms don't work on views but on the *models* which the views show.

A view is nothing but a window which transforms bits in memory to something a user can find useful.

So what you really want is to separate the models in your views from the views themselves. That will also make testing much more simple. Have them publish events when they are change.

Your algorithm should subscribe to the events of all four models and do its work, putting the result in another model where the same or other views can pick it up.

In the views, also subscribe to the appropriate events which your models emit and update them accordingly.

This way, you can separate the model from the views. You won't get into trouble when the user rearranges views or closes them.

Comment: Hi, I agree with your advice.  I'm developing an MVP design, but with 4 V (views).  The algorithm you're describing is in my Model.  I now need to find a tidy location to put the 'P' that ties the Model to the Views.  It may seem strange to have 4*V in an MVP, but they're really just one view: it's just that I want to allow the user to drag out & independently resize individual parts of the view.  Can you recommend where I position the P code?  Ideally I want to trigger the processing once startup is complete and the Views are realised.

Comment: Why? Just start the processing when the model is ready and let the views care for themselves. Try to avoid tight coupling. In your case, an event driven approach should work great.

Comment: Aah, I see Aaron.  Create the model at application startup, then let the views register themselves into the model post-initialise.  I can't let the UI be completely View-driven, since the Views display data received across the network, plus get enabled/disabled dependent on network activity.

Comment: Yes. Create a global "event" service or something and let each component of the model publish events via this global hub. Any interested party can then subscribe to events from the hub. For example, views can respond to "calculation finished" or "rows updated" events to refresh themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is setup a Perspective with those views and lock them, so the user may not close them.

I do not remember exactly how you can do this, but I think setting the perspective as 'fixed' on the extension point declaration might do the trick.

Comment: Note: If you don't lock them and the user closes a view accidentally, he can always restore the view with "Reset Perspective..."

Comment: Hi, as the question indicated, the new plugin wizard has provided me with a perspective.  The plugin manifest editor has allowed me to create a 'perspectiveExtension' for each view, and mark use this to mark them non-closeable.